React Native Expo + @legendapp/state : Only one user syncs when going online after adding multiple users offline
I'm building a "local-first" mobile app using React Native and Expo. My goal is to allow users to add data offline, which gets synced to the API server when the app goes online. I'm using @legendapp/state for managing observable state and MMKV for offline persistence.
The issue I'm encountering is that when I add multiple users offline, only one user gets synced to the server when I come back online. However, if I refresh the app, all pending users get posted to the API server.
Here is the relevant code in my Expo project:
import React from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  FlatList,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  Button,
  Alert,
} from "react-native";
import { observable } from "@legendapp/state";
import { syncedFetch } from "@legendapp/state/sync-plugins/fetch";
import { synced } from "@legendapp/state/sync";
import { observer } from "@legendapp/state/react";
import { ObservablePersistMMKV } from "@legendapp/state/persist-plugins/mmkv";

const store$ = observable({
  users: synced({
    initial: [],
    get: () =>
      fetch("http://192.168.0.80:8080/api/users")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          return data.content; // Assuming the JSON response contains a `content` array
        }),
    set: async ({ changes, onError }) => {
      return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
          const pendingUsers = changes
            .filter((change) => !change.prevAtPath && change.valueAtPath) // New users
            .map((change) => change.valueAtPath);

          if (pendingUsers.length === 0) {
            console.log("No new users to sync.");
            return resolve(); // Resolve immediately if no users to sync
          }

          const syncPromises = pendingUsers.map(async (user) => {
            try {
              const response = await fetch(
                "http://192.168.0.80:8080/api/users",
                {
                  method: "POST",
                  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                  body: JSON.stringify(user),
                }
              );
              if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(
                  `Failed to sync user. HTTP status: ${response.status}`
                );
              }
              const result = await response.json();
              console.log("User synced successfully:", result);
            } catch (error) {
              console.error("Error syncing user:", error.message || error);
              if (onError) {
                console.error("onError...")
                onError(error, { user, retryCount: 1, backoff: 2000 });
              }
            }
          });
          // Wait for all promises to complete
          await Promise.all(syncPromises);
          resolve(); // Resolve the promise after all sync operations
        } catch (err) {
          reject(err); // Reject the promise if an unexpected error occurs
        }
      });
    },
    changesSince: "last-sync",
    persist: {
      plugin: ObservablePersistMMKV,
      name: "messages",
      retrySync: true,
    },
    retry: {
      // infinite: true,
      maxDelay: 30,
      // backoff: 'exponential',
    },
    debounceSet: 500,
  }),
});
// content
export default observer(function TabOneScreen() {
  // Add random user handler
  const handleAddRandomUser = () => {
    const randomUser = {
      // id: Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9),
      firstName: "Random",
      lastName: "User",
      email: `random.user${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)}@example.com`,
      pictureUrl: "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/67.jpg",
    };
    // Update the observable store with the new user
    store$.users.push(randomUser);
    // store$.users.set(randomUser);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title="Add Random User" onPress={handleAddRandomUser} />

      <FlatList
        data={store$.users.get()}
        keyExtractor={(item) =>
          item.id ? item.id.toString() : Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9)
        }
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View style={styles.userCard}>
            <Image
              source={{
                uri:
                  item.pictureUrl ||
                  "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/68.jpg",
              }}
              style={styles.avatar}
            />
            <View style={styles.userInfo}>
              <Text
                style={styles.userName}
              >{`${item.firstName} ${item.lastName}`}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.userEmail}>{item.email}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 20,
    backgroundColor: "#f9f9f9",
  },
  userCard: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    padding: 15,
    marginVertical: 5,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    borderRadius: 8,
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOpacity: 0.1,
    shadowRadius: 4,
    elevation: 2,
  },
  avatar: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 25,
    marginRight: 15,
  },
  userInfo: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  userName: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  userEmail: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: "#555",
  },
});

Problem Details:
When offline, I add multiple users using the "Add Random User" button.
Upon going back online, only one user is sent to the server, and the others remain unsynced.
If I refresh the app, all pending users are successfully synced to the server
Error Logs:
Encrypted: false)
 (NOBRIDGE) ERROR  Error syncing user: Network request failed
 (NOBRIDGE) ERROR  onError...
 (NOBRIDGE) ERROR  Error syncing user: Network request failed
 (NOBRIDGE) ERROR  onError...
 (NOBRIDGE) ERROR  Error syncing user: Network request failed
 (NOBRIDGE) ERROR  onError...
 (NOBRIDGE) LOG  User synced successfully: {"age": null, "email": "random.user72@example.com", "firstName": "Random", "gender": null, "id": 3, "lastName": "User", "pictureUrl": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/67.jpg"}
 (NOBRIDGE) WARN  [legend-state] Warning: Multiple elements in array have the same ID. Key field: id, Array: [{"age": 58, "email": "tomine.klepp@example.com", "firstName": "Tomine", "gender": "female", "id": 1, "lastName": "Klepp", "pictureUrl": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/40.jpg"}, {"age": 34, "email": "johan.larsen@example.com", "firstName": "Johan", "gender": "male", "id": 2, "lastName": "Larsen", "pictureUrl": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/44.jpg"}, {"email": "random.user72@example.com", "firstName": "Random", "lastName": "User", "pictureUrl": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/67.jpg"}, {"email": "random.user4@example.com", "firstName": "Random", "lastName": "User", "pictureUrl": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/67.jpg"}]
 (NOBRIDGE) LOG  User synced successfully: {"age": null, "email": "random.user4@example.com", "firstName": "Random", "gender": null, "id": 4, "lastName": "User", "pictureUrl": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/67.jpg"}

package.json:
{
  "name": "app",
  "main": "expo-router/entry",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "test": "jest --watchAll"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.2",
    "@legendapp/state": "^3.0.0-beta.19",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^2.1.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^7.0.0",
    "expo": "~52.0.20",
    "expo-dev-client": "~5.0.6",
    "expo-font": "~13.0.2",
    "expo-linking": "~7.0.3",
    "expo-router": "~4.0.14",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.29.18",
    "expo-status-bar": "~2.0.0",
    "expo-system-ui": "~4.0.6",
    "expo-web-browser": "~14.0.1",
    "react": "18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "18.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.76.5",
    "react-native-mmkv": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.16.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.12.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~4.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.13",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.25.2",
    "@types/react": "~18.3.12",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "jest-expo": "~52.0.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.3.1",
    "typescript": "~5.3.3"
  },
  "private": true
}


the /user api gives response like this:
/api/users
{"content":[{"id":1,"firstName":"Tomine","lastName":"Klepp","gender":"female","age":58,"email":"tomine.klepp@example.com","pictureUrl":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/40.jpg"},{"id":2,"firstName":"Johan","lastName":"Larsen","gender":"male","age":34,"email":"johan.larsen@example.com","pictureUrl":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/44.jpg"},{"id":3,"firstName":"Random","lastName":"User","gender":null,"age":null,"email":"random.user72@example.com","pictureUrl":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/67.jpg"},{"id":4,"firstName":"Random","lastName":"User","gender":null,"age":null,"email":"random.user4@example.com","pictureUrl":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/67.jpg"}],"pageable":{"sort":{"empty":true,"unsorted":true,"sorted":false},"offset":0,"pageNumber":0,"pageSize":10,"paged":true,"unpaged":false},"last":true,"totalPages":1,"totalElements":4,"first":true,"size":10,"number":0,"sort":{"empty":true,"unsorted":true,"sorted":false},"numberOfElements":4,"empty":false}

and the post /user body should something like this:
  {
         "firstName":"Tomine",
         "lastName":"Klepp",
         "gender":"female",
         "age":58,
         "email":"tomine.klepp@example.com",
         "pictureUrl":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/40.jpg"
      }


I encountered an issue with the set function in my application that was causing unexpected behavior. After some investigation and experimentation, I identified that the root cause was in the configuration settings for retry and debounce. Here's how I resolved the problem:
import React from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  FlatList,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  Button,
  Alert,
} from "react-native";
import { observable } from "@legendapp/state";
import { syncedFetch } from "@legendapp/state/sync-plugins/fetch";
import { synced } from "@legendapp/state/sync";
import { observer } from "@legendapp/state/react";
import { ObservablePersistMMKV } from "@legendapp/state/persist-plugins/mmkv";

const store$ = observable({
  users: synced({
    initial: [],
    get: () =>
      fetch("http://192.168.0.80:8080/api/users")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          return data.content; 
        }),
        set: async ({ changes, onError }) => {
          return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            try {
              const pendingUsers = changes
                .filter((change) => !change.prevAtPath && change.valueAtPath)
                .map((change) => change.valueAtPath);
        
              if (pendingUsers.length === 0) {
                console.log("No new users to sync.");
                return resolve(); 
              }
        
              let errorHandled = false; // Flag to ensure onError is called only once
        
              for (const user of pendingUsers) {
                try {
                  const response = await fetch(
                    "http://192.168.0.80:8080/api/users",
                    {
                      method: "POST",
                      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                      body: JSON.stringify(user),
                    }
                  );
        
                  if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error(
                      `Failed to sync user. HTTP status: ${response.status}`
                    );
                  }
        
                  const result = await response.json();
                  console.log("User synced successfully:", result);
                } catch (error) {
                  if (!errorHandled && onError) {
                    errorHandled = true; // Mark error as handled
                    onError(error, { user, retryCount: 1, backoff: 7000 });
                  }
                  break; // Exit the loop after handling the first error
                }
              }
        
              resolve(); // Resolve the promise if all is successful
            } catch (err) {
              reject(err); // Reject the promise on unexpected errors
            }
          });
        },
    changesSince: "last-sync",
    persist: {
      plugin: ObservablePersistMMKV,
      name: "messages",
      retrySync: true,
    },
    retry: {
      infinite: true,
      maxDelay: 30,
      backoff: 'exponential',
    },
    debounceSet: 5000,
  }),
});
export default observer(function TabOneScreen() {
  const handleAddRandomUser = () => {
    const randomUser = {
      firstName: "Random",
      lastName: "User",
      email: `random.user${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)}@example.com`,
      pictureUrl: "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/67.jpg",
    };
    store$.users.push(randomUser);
    // store$.users.set(randomUser);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title="Add Random User" onPress={handleAddRandomUser} />

      <FlatList
        data={store$.users.get()}
        keyExtractor={(item) =>
          item.id ? item.id.toString() : Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9)
        }
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View style={styles.userCard}>
            <Image
              source={{
                uri:
                  item.pictureUrl ||
                  "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/68.jpg",
              }}
              style={styles.avatar}
            />
            <View style={styles.userInfo}>
              <Text
                style={styles.userName}
              >{`${item.firstName} ${item.lastName}`}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.userEmail}>{item.email}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 20,
    backgroundColor: "#f9f9f9",
  },
  userCard: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    padding: 15,
    marginVertical: 5,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    borderRadius: 8,
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOpacity: 0.1,
    shadowRadius: 4,
    elevation: 2,
  },
  avatar: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 25,
    marginRight: 15,
  },
  userInfo: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  userName: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  userEmail: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: "#555",
  },
});

